# Can someone accept her/his own answer to get the unsung hero badge?

Tags: support, answers, badges, accepted-answers

I came over these two questions, which looked awkward due to the fact that the user has accepted his own answer.

> Examples:
>
> [How to use/apply class inheritance in Enchant.js](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57899/how-to-use-apply-class-inheritance-in-enchant-js)
>
> [How can I place my Enchant.js game into a DIV in a fully-designed web site?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55032/how-can-i-place-my-enchant-js-game-into-a-div-in-a-fully-designed-web-site)

Can you get the unsung hero badge, from accepting your own answers?

Comment: Hmmm. Loophole?

Comment: @JohnMcDonald that would also be my guess, I wonder if it really is :)

Comment: I suppose it's possible. However, the user you linked only has one answer that qualifies. The accepted answer needs to have zero score to qualify towards the unsung hero. They would need an additional 9 answers accepted with zero score to get the badge.

Comment: At StackOverflow, I'd have Unsung Hero if it allowed self-accepted answers. As it is, I just need one or two more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Self accepted answers do not count**, [authoritative answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57245) and [here, where it also states that only answers older than 10 days (with no votes) are considered.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57834) Also wiki answers and deleted answers are not considered.

See also: [List of all badges with full description.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397)

Comment: Just confirmed this is still true: `And a.OwnerUserId <> Isnull(q.OwnerUserId, -1)`